# Start Idlex instead of Idle with Launcher Symbol

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-idle

I'm running with Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.12.
I downloaded and installed Idlex and can start the editor with the extensions, using the terminal in the folder, where the idlex.py file is.

Is it possible, to create a shortcut in the launcher like the standard Idle, such that Idlex is loaded by default?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make it's entry in $PATH veriable than

Go to system settings 
click on Details 
click on default application 
set it here

OR

right click -> Properties
Go to open with tab 
set it here or use command

Or

Use Ubuntu Tweak

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```